# how to add items to a JTable using a loop

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I came up with this loop here:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < memberArrayList.size(); i++){
        int j = 0;
        memberTable.setValueAt(memberArrayList.get(i).getFirstName(), i, j);
        j++;
        memberTable.setValueAt(memberArrayList.get(i).getLastName(), i, j);
        j++;
        memberTable.setValueAt(memberArrayList.get(i).getEmail(), i, j);
        j++;
        memberTable.setValueAt(memberArrayList.get(i).getPhoneNumber(), i, j);
        j++;
        memberTable.setValueAt(memberArrayList.get(i).getLevel(), i, j);
    }
```

It works but I'm sure there is a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer will depend on what type of `TableModel` you are using, for example, if you are using a `DefaultTableModel` you could use something like...

```
DefaultTableModel memberTable= ...;

for(int i = 0; i < memberArrayList.size(); i++){
    Object[] rowData = new Object[]{
        memberArrayList.get(i).getFirstName(),
        memberArrayList.get(i).getLastName(), 
        memberArrayList.get(i).getEmail(), 
        memberArrayList.get(i).getPhoneNumber(),
        memberArrayList.get(i).getLevel()
        };
    memberTable.addRow(rowData);
}
```

This assumes that you only want to add rows to the end of the table model ;)

Personally, I'd prefer to add each member to the table model as a single entity, but that's just me

Take a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details...

Answer (score 2):

Swing components are using MVC pattern. JTable is the view, TableModels are the model that contains data.

you can subclass [`AbstractTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) to achieve your goal.

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    // override these methods:
    // getColumnCount, getRowCount, getValueAt
    // and add data manipulation methods
}
```

then your table is created using MyTableModel

```
MyTableModel mtm = new MyTableModel(......);
JTable table = new JTable(mtm);
```

then call data manipulation methods in mtm. something like

```
mtm.addPerson(new Person(......));
```

Comment: I liked your approach of dealing with each row as a `Person` object.  Having said that, I'd tend to extend and change a `DefaultTableModel` for this, given it provides sensible return values for most methods of `AbstractTabelModel`.  Also note that the link to the docs is best included as an [edit to the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23486075/edit).

Comment: Don't forget to fire appropriate event notification when adding new content ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, any modification (not only adding) to the inner data should fire a proper event.

Comment: @XingFei As far as the comment about editing goes, any thanks would be better expressed by you *editing the answer to **add** the link.* ;)  I'll do it this time.. :)