# Dynamic row creation in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Initially I want jtable with one row, when I enter the last row, new row will create with the same format of previous row. Is it possible in jtable or any other options are available in java?

Comment: [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) supports adding rows dynamically, but you can create your own `TableModel` to do it as well (which is typically more functional).  Take a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485987/how-to-add-items-to-a-jtable-using-a-loop/23486044#23486044) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117334/i-want-to-update-table-when-button-is-clicked/30117380#30117380) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785982/how-to-refresh-data-in-jtable-i-am-using-tablemodel/16786120#16786120)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DefaultTableModel for your table. This provides you addRow method which can be used to add rows dynamically.

Using DefaultTableModel:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(0, 0);
// Create your table column headers
    String header[] = new String[] { "Column1", "Column2", "Column3" };
    dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(header);
```

Now create Rows dyamically using addRow api

```
Vector<Object> data = new Vector<Object>();
        data.add("Data1");
        data.add("Data2");
        data.add("Data3");
dtm.add(data);
```

Hope this will help..

Comment: ya finally i got the solution from Kailas concepts,

my code is Here:

DefaultTableModel tmodel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
tmodel.addRow(temp);
Thank you for your valuable solutions.